# CPack create packages with executables from different source tree

Tags: cmake, package, cpack

The problem is as follows:

### Project structure:

```
ProjectDir
- CMakeLists.txt
- src
-- CMakeLists.txt
-- FirstApp
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- ... sources ...
-- SecondApp
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- ... sources ...
- tools
-- CMakeLists.txt
-- SomeTool
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- ... sources ...
-- SomeOtherTool
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- ... sources ...
```

### What I want to achieve is:

- package (let it be *rpm* or *deb*) with **SomeTool** binaries;
- package with **FirstApp**, **SecondApp** AND **SomeOtherTool** binaries;

As far as I know:

- CPack is putting into packages content the stuff that is defined in **install** command;
- CPack cannot be called ( `include(CPack)` ) twice in the same tree (for example it cannot be called in CMakeLists.txt at `src` level AND `SecondApp` level);

### What do I have

In `ProjectDir/tools/SomeTool/CMakeLists.txt` I've (it's pseado code):

```
PROJECT( SomeTool )

SET(TARGET SomeTool)

SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "SomeTool")
# ...
# all the other CPACK_* stuff
# ...

include(CPack)
add_custom_target(${TARGET}-package 
                  COMMAND cpack --config "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CPack${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake")

SET(SOURCES ...)
SET(HEADERS ...)
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
install(TARGETS ${TARGET}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/bin)
```

This way I can call `make SomeTool-package` and it'll create package (`SomeTool.rpm`) with content `/usr/bin/SomeTool`. Great!

---

I can have very similar `CMakeLists.txt` in `ProjectDir/src/` dir:

```
# src/CMakeLists.txt
PROJECT( MainProject )

SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "MainProject")
# ...
# all the other CPACK_* stuff
# ...

include(CPack)
add_custom_target(MainProject-package 
                  COMMAND cpack --config "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CPack${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake")

add_subdirectory(FirstApp)
add_subdirectory(SecondApp)

# src/FirstApp/CMakeLists.txt
SET(TARGET FirstApp)
SET(SOURCES ...)
SET(HEADERS ...)
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
install(TARGETS ${TARGET}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/bin)

# src/SecondApp/CMakeLists.txt
SET(TARGET SecondApp)
SET(SOURCES ...)
SET(HEADERS ...)
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
install(TARGETS ${TARGET}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/bin)
```

This way I can call `make MainProject-package` and it'll create package (`MainProject.rpm`) with content `/usr/bin/FirstApp` and `/usr/bin/SecondApp`. Great!

**SomeOtherTool** also have a `CMakeLists.txt` which looks the same as **FirstApp** and **SecondApp** `CMakeLists.txt` and I can call `make SomeOtherTool` and it'll produce `SomeOtherTool` binaries.

### The Question

As CPack is puting into packages stuff connected to `install` command, how can I connect **SomeOtherTool** with my **MainProject-package** ?

My solution would (is) be to put another `install` clause at the end of `src/CMakeLists.txt` that'd look like:

```
add_dependency(MainProject SomeOtherTool)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SomeOtherTool DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/usr/bin )
```

Is there any other way? This solution doesn't look clean.. If I change the **SomeOtherTool** executable name I'll have to change it in here also. The same goes with install path.